# 歩数計の機能をつけたiosアプリを作りたい

Tags: swift, ios

プログラミング初心者です。

歩数計の機能を付けたiosアプリを作るためには、どのようなコードを書けば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: iOSではシステムで歩数情報を取得・蓄積出来るようになっており、コードからは`HealthKit`や`CMPedometer`などを使ってアクセスできます。"ios swift 歩数"なんかをキーワードにして検索すると、日本語での解説記事もいくつかヒットします。「歩数計の機能を付けたiosアプリ」と言うだけでは、具体的に「どのようなコード」と示すことはできません。もう少しご自分でも調べてみて、どんな機能なのか具体的に説明した上で、質問範囲を具体化して絞り込んでください。

Answer (score 0):

加速度センサーの値を読み取って、それを積分することで位置情報を得るというのが基本だと思います。
人の動きは単純ではないので、ノイズ除去などの処理と、一歩の動きの同定が必要になると思います。

加速度センサーの値を読み取るコードは、[XCode8 Swift3 で iOS 9.3 用加速度センサー値取得のサンプルアプリ](https://qiita.com/motokazu/items/ef7a83b8e693d038de3b)　の記事が参考になると思います。